# Is there any way to replay events in a date range?

Tags: spring-boot, event-driven, axon

I am implementing an example of spring-boot and axon. I have two events 
(deposit and withdraw account balance). I want to know is there any way to get the state of the Account Aggregate by a given date ?
I want to get not just the final state, but to replay events in a range of dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help with this.

In the context of Axon Framework, you can start a replay of events by telling a given `TrackingEventProcessor` to 'reset' it's Tokens. By the way, the current description on this in the Reference Guide can be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#replaying-events).

These `TrackingTokens` are the objects which know how far a given `TrackingEventProcessor` is in terms of handling events from the Event Stream. Thus resetting/adjusting these `TrackingTokens` is what will issue a Replay of events.

Knowing all these, the second step is to look at the methods the `TrackingEventProcessor` provides to 'reset tokens', which is threefold:

1. `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens()`
2. `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens(Function<StreamableMessageSource, TrackingToken>)`
3. `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens(TrackingToken)`

Option one will reset your tokens to the beginning of the event stream, which will thus replay everything.
Option two and three however give you the opportunity to provide a `TrackingToken`.

Thus, you could provide a `TrackingToken` starting from several points on the Event Stream. So, how do you go about to creating such a `TrackingToken` at a specific point in time? To that end, you should take a look at the `StreamableMessageSource` interface, which has the following operations:

1. `StreamableMessageSource#createTailToken()`
2. `StreamableMessageSource#createHeadToken()`
3. `StreamableMessageSource#createTokenAt(Instant)`
4. `StreamableMessageSource#createTokenSince(Duration)`

Option 1 is what's used to create a token at the start of the stream, whilst 2 will create a token at the head of the stream.

Option 3 and 4 will however allow you to create a token at a specific point in time, thus allowing you to replay all the events since the defined instance up to now.

There is one caveat in this scenario however. You're asking to replay an Aggregate. From Axon's perspective by default the Aggregate is the Command Model in a CQRS set up, thus dealing with Commands going in to your system. In the majority of the applications, you want Commands (e.g. the requests to change something) to occur on the **current** state of the application. As such, the `Repository` provided to retrieve an Aggregate does not allow specifying a point in time.

The above described solution in regards to replaying is thus solely tied to Query Model creation, as the `TrackingEventProcessor` is part of the Event Handling side in your application most often used to create views. This idea also ties in with your questions, that you want to know the "state of the Account Aggregate" at a given point in time. That's not a *command*, but a *query*, as you have 'a request for data' instead of 'the request to change state'.

Hope this helps you out @Safe!